# Threads are increasing but not decreasing when the task finished in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

I have an application that I did thread configuration as follows,

```
corepoolsize = 10
maxpoolsize = 10
queuecapacity = 10
```

But when I do use Threads and functions that run on threads (asynchronous process)
I see it is increasing like the follows, But I don't see the threads are decreasing. Is that a indication of memory leak? Can anybody guide me?

Log prints like this,

```
2021-09-15 01:13:48.554  INFO 111 --- [Async-1]
2021-09-15 01:13:48.654  INFO 121 --- [Async-2]
2021-09-15 01:13:48.754  INFO 132 --- [Async-3]
2021-09-15 01:13:48.854  INFO 140 --- [Async-4]
2021-09-15 01:13:48.954  INFO 155 --- [Async-5]
2021-09-15 01:13:49.554  INFO 160 --- [Async-6]
```

But I don't see it is calling again `[Async-1], [Async-2]` like that. Is this a memory leak or a thread cache or after filling up corepoolsize then will it run `[Async-1]`?

Comment: Can you please add a full example reproducing the issue? We cannot otherwise help, as we cannot understand the problem that you face.

Comment: you have a core pool size of `10`, so the core pool will contain the threads `Async-1` to `Async-10` after 10 tasks I assume that the next thread to execute a task may be the one that was idle the most. Note that it will be one from 10 created earlier

Comment: From ThreadPoolExecutor: _corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, unless allowCoreThreadTimeOut is set_. No leackage, though you could set it to for instance 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The documentation for [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) explicitly states:

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), if fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.

Comment: There is no evidence in the question that he is using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @user207421 some kind of thread pool there is.

Comment: @user207421 the OP writes about the configuration parameters "corepoolsize", "maxpoolsize" and "maxpoolsize" and he mentions also "spring-boot", which uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` for executing asynchronous task, so it seems reasonable to expect the a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is used behind the scenes.

Comment: @JoopEggen Of course but there is nothing about `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the question. If there is a valid inference from the evidence to that conclusion it should have been provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Corepoolsize` represents the worker thread that is always alive.

You can check `ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker`,  `ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask` method, these worker threads will always try to get tasks from the task queue and execute them. So if no new tasks are posted to the thread pool, then these worker threads will always live, usually blocked in the `take` method of `workQueue`, So you don't have to worry about the cpu idling.

Worker threads outside the number of corepoolsize will be recycled, still `ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask` method:

```
           try {
                Runnable r = timed ?
                    workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                    workQueue.take();
                if (r != null)
                    return r;
                timedOut = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
                timedOut = false;
            }
```

These threads to be recycled can survive at most `keepAliveTime` time.

The thread pool uses a Hash table to hold the thread's reference, so that the life cycle of the thread can be controlled by operations such as adding and removing references.(`ThreadPoolExecutor#processWorkerExit` method).